# Create and compare array for results

Tags: php, arrays

Learning curve question. I have searched and the answers elude me.
How can I take a basic result such as $row->product_id which returns a total of $limit items and turn it into an array that can then be used in  another query to get more results.

```
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();  
foreach($rows as $row){
        echo '<div>' . $row->product_id . '</a></div>';
        }
```

This gets me the results to echo but I need to use them again in another query.

```
$query="select my_colum from my_table where myItem_Array_results LIMIT
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use results of a `SELECT` in another query?
Than you should do the whole operation in MySQL. Read about [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///join.html). Not only is it more clear and logical, but also much faster.

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `my_table` ON `my_table`.`my_column` = `products`.`id`
```

Comment: I have moved on finally as I learned that I was already getting my results. I thought adding them into another query would be the way but it just didn't work for me. As of right now I have many left|inner joins going on. I figured out how to even remove duplicates. Now I face another problem. I thank you for your reply and in fact read that linked page.

Answer (score -1):

My php is rusty but try something like this:

```
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $product_ids = array();
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();  
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $product_ids[] = $row->product_id;
        echo '<div>' . $row->product_id . '</a></div>';
    }
```